# select elements with same id and different attribute jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list `ul` where at least two rows has the same `id` but with a different attribute value `id-type`

**CODE TRIED**

In this code I only outline both rows (same Id), how can I fix this?

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){

$("ul").find("li#post1").css("border","5px solid red");


});
```

```css
li{margin:5px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
<li id='post1' id-type='1'> I dont want to be selected</li>

<li id='post1' id-type='2'> I want to be selected only</li>


<li id='post3' id-type='2'> text</li>

<li id='post2' id-type='2'> text</li>
</ul>
<button>elegir id='post1' id-type='2'</button>
```

Comment: You can't have 2 elements with the same id as ids have to be unique, otherwise your HTML is not valid. You can use classes instead.

Comment: Note that an [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) "must be unique in the whole document". Also see [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: Technically "cannot" should be "should not", but I completely agree.

Comment: @matthias_h ok, i can fix that right away, but the question is how should I make my code work?

Comment: @max The answer is already given :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDs are supposed to unique in DOM. So, you can change all ids to class instead and then you can access `id-type='2'` element easily like:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("ul").find("li.post1[id-type='2']").css("border", "5px solid red");
});
```

```css
li {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='post1' id-type='1'> I dont want to be selected</li>
  <li class='post1' id-type='2'> I want to be selected only</li>
  <li class='post3' id-type='2'> text</li>
  <li class='post2' id-type='2'> text</li>
</ul>
<button>elegir id='post1' id-type='2'</button>
```